# Injecting fragment via hilt using fragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, dagger-hilt

I'm wondering if I'm using hilt correctly. I'd like to replace some content in main activity with fragment, which should be injected via hilt. Main activity looks like this:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var mainFragment: MainFragment

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, mainFragment)
                .commitNow()
        }
    }
}
```

And my fragment looks like this:

```
class MainFragment @Inject constructor() : Fragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var someDependency: SomeDependency

    //onCreateView(), onViewCreated()
}
```

My questions here:

1. Is it safe to let hilt managing an instance of MainFragment? What in case of screen rotation?
2. My fragment should not be annotated with `@AndroidEntryPoint` as it's dynamically injected into my main activity, so actually it is not an entry point?

Comment: What do you mean that it shouldn't be annotated with @AndroidEntryPoint?

Comment: AndroidEntryPoint on fragment combined with Inject is pointless to me as Inject annotation already asks Hilt to provide required dependencies.

Comment: Aahh, I meant it's not present in XML view and it needs to be created by me (or injected into Activity, like in example).

Comment: But how should I create it? Right now I let hilt to create it and then injecting it in activity. Is this ok?

Comment: If I remove remove "inject constructor()" and add the annotation AndroidEntryPoint to fragment then error is being thrown by hilt that MainFragment cannot be provided, hence it cannot be injected into MainActivity.

Comment: If I create it manually in activity via non-parameter constructor then fragment's dependencies would not be injected (lateinit var someDependency: SomeDependency). Moreover, I shouldn't create it by myself as it should have the AndroidEntryPoint annotation according to your suggestion, so it should be managed by Hilt, not by me.

Comment: Yes, they would. That's how Hilt works. I don't know what to tell you. What you are doing is something horribly wrong(holding a reference to the fragment itself). If you use `@AndroidEntryPoint` Hilt takes care of its dependencies already. If you want your custom fragment factory then inject that and not the fragment itself and request it from there but if all you care about are dependencies - `@AndroidEntryPoint` is enough.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, it injected dependencies, even though I invoked constructor by myself. Yeah, I know holding a reference to a fragment is horrible idea, but I see no other way to make it work with fragment manager. I need to somehow get fragment in activity, but how? What you are suggesting is to create some kind of fragment factory instead of creating it manually? And then inject this factory into activity and let factory to return this fragment when fragment manager replaces container with this fragment?

Comment: What I meant is the official [FragmentFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentFactory) that allows you to handle fragment instantiation by yourself, because I thought that is what you want and the main reason why I was saying that you don't need it is because Hilt already takes care of most of the issues, hence why it was created. Now your problem is that you need to have a reference for the fragment for some reason. No.1 that's is beyond the scope of the question. No.2 Again, that is anti-pattern and most likely can be solved other way.

Comment: No, I don't need to have a reference to a fragment in Activity. I did it only because I wanted to let Hilt to inject this in MainActivity. So the resolution is to get rid of reference in activity, ask FragmentFactory to provide MainFragment and last but not least annotate MainFragment with AndroidEntryPoint?

Comment: If all you want is to have Hilt dependencies in a fragment. All you have to do is add the annotation. And if you have to do is create an instance from empty constructor. Hilt a lot of things under the hood so if a fragment has that annotation and someone asks for it, it already gives it with all of its dependencies.

Comment: Nice, thanks, didn't expect that invoking empty constructor for fragment annotated with AndroidEntryPoint will result in Fragment with injected dependencies. This resolves my issue, thanks.

Comment: Actually, you sort of cracked my knowledge because I am not 1000% sure so I'll need to check it but overall, you should let Hilt handle it and not hold a reference to the fragment.